# Easiest way to swap childElements in parentNode with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dom-events

When i drag an element onto another element of the same parentNode i want the two elements two swap position.
I keep track of the targets with two addEventListeners and i already tried to swap the important things like the classes and the textContent with storing that data in temporary helper variables but this procedure only worked for the first element to be copied into another but without making the first element like how the second element was.

```
<style>
  .objects > div {
    margin: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

.one { background-color: lightblue;}
.two { background-color: lightcoral;}
.three { background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;}
</style>



<body>
  <div class="objects">
    <div draggable='true' class='one' id='o1'>A</div>
    <div draggable='true' class='two' id='o2'>B</div>
    <div draggable='true' class='three' id='o2'>C</div>

  </div>

</body>
```

```
var objects = document.querySelector('.objects');


objects.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {

  objects.addEventListener('dragover', function(e2) { e2.preventDefault() });
  objects.addEventListener('drop', function dandd(e2) {

    //how can i swap both
    var tempText = e.target.textContent; 
    var tempClass = e.target.classList;
    
    e.target.textContent = e2.target.textContent;
    e.target.classList = e2.target.classList;

    e2.target.textContent = tempText;
    e2.target.classList = tempClass;
    

  objects.removeEventListener('drop', dandd);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi to start with have a look at querySelector - it is not doing what you think I believe as it only selects one element. You need to go through all of the draggable elements adding an event listener if you want them all to be draggable. Also, you don't need to store info on each element in the way you describe as swapping the elements in the DOM will be enough, but first get the eventlisteners set up..

Comment: sorry for being unprecise, i edited my code. now you see that i have the event.target, i.e. the childElements. So i have access to the concrete child and not only the parent. (becuase in my real code there are a lot of children, so adding an addeventlistener to all of them is not feasible). But still, i cannot sap them with this method.